# How exactly do SharePoint 2010 List Views behave?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, custom-list, synchronisation

I was under the assumption that once I create a list, I can drop it on as many sites/pages I wanted and they would behave as views of the original list and stay in sync.

In other words, If I were to make a change (edit/modify) to the original list, all other pages/sites that I had dropped the list view web part into would reflect the change.

From trying this out on a SharePoint Standard 2010 env. it did not seem true.

Am I missing something or do all list view web parts just behave as Independent copy of the original lists themselves?

If so, is there a workaround to this?

I am looking to create a single list and drop views of it on different pages in order to control permissions.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You place a List-WebPart on a page and choose the view that it should use from the drop down menu. Now your WebPart obtains a copy of the list view that you selected. This will remain constant even if you modify the original view in the list itself.

So, the behaviour you have described in your question is standard SharePoint behavior: List view changes are NOT propagated to any WebParts that display this list. Please note, the content shown by your WebPart is always up to date. It's only the view (e.g. which columns are displayed or how to sort items) that is static for your WebParts.