# trouble when updating view programmatically

Tags: list, visual-studio, list-view, view

I got the following event code wich is called when clicking a button:

```
void addSubject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
 thisWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

 SPList productList = thisWeb.List["Documents"];
 SPview view = productList.Views["All Items"];

 view.ViewFields.Add("Subject");

 view.Update();
 productList.Update();
}
```

On my sitepage, where I inserted the "Documents" web part, nothing happens. However if I click on the "Documents" link to the left to only see the "Documents" list, I can see the view has changed. Also if I choose "Edit web part" and change "Selected View" I can see the changes...So how do I see the changes directly when clicking the button??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to the same page again, its not refreshing the View on the page!

**EDIT:**

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
```

Comment: Alright..Sorry for being stupid but how exactly do I do that with code?

Comment: @Jukke, see edited part

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I get an error: "the name 'response' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Jukke see new update!

Answer (score 0):

The View changes will not be displayed in the Documents WebPart. This is a standard SharePoint behavior. The given link has more information:
[How exactly do SharePoint 2010 List Views behave?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75709/how-exactly-do-sharepoint-2010-list-views-behave/75718#75718)